# How to add values dynamically in DropDownPicker dynamically React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

In DropDownPicker I am trying to add map dynamically which's failing in syntax. **Need help with the syntax as it looks logically correct to me**. I was able to find loop example for Picker but not for DropDownPicker

```
<View>
<DropDownPicker
          items={[
            mealItems.map((option) =>(
             {
              label: {option.name}, // Getting error here
              value:{option.id},
              icon: () => (                  
                <View style={styles.arrowAdd}>
                  <FoodPlus />
                </View>
              ),
            }, //Getting error here to remove the comma but that's required 
            )
            )
          ]
          }
//Dropdown attributes such as  style etc
/>
      </View>
```

My response data that I am trying to loop looks like following:

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "Breakfast"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Morning Snack"}, {"id": 3, "name": "Lunch"}, {"id": 4, "name": "Evening Snack"}, {"id": 5, "name": "Dinner"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up where you need JSX syntax vs regular Javascript syntax. The biggest issue is with the map functions return value. You don't need `{}` around the values because there you should be using the JavaScript Object notation.

After fixing the issues it should look like this.

```
<View>
  <DropDownPicker
    items={mealItems.map((option) => ({
      label: option.name,
      value: option.id,
      icon: () => (
        <View style={styles.arrowAdd}>
          <FoodPlus />
        </View>
      ),
    }))}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: Hi!
It says name doesn't exist on type 'never'
same with id

Comment: @Sakshi are you using TypeScript?

Comment: Yes using tsx file type

Comment: It looks like `mealItems` is not strongly typed so the compiler doesn't know what the type of `option` is. It then gives you a warning because it might not exist and could cause an error. Either strongly type the `mealItems` array so that the types of `option` can be inferred or mark `option` as an `any` type i.e. `mealItems.map((option: any) => ({`